# How to initialize and accumulate the integer value when I change views?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have 2 views first view to keep and accumulate integer value to move my image.

The second view to generate the random number and send it to the first view to accumulate the value each time switching between these 2 views.

First view .h

```
 int move;
```

First .m

```
// to get random value and accumulate value
-(void)getMovepoint:(int)number{
moveValue += number;
}

// to move my image
- (void)viewDidLoad{
double xPos;
double yPos;
xPos = [[P1XArraypos objectAtIndex:moveValue]intValue];
yPos = [[P1YArraypos objectAtIndex:moveValue]intValue];
image.center= CGPointMake(xPos,yPos);
```

Second view .h

```
int randomMove;
```

Second view .m

```
randomMove = arc4random() % 6+1;
[board getMovepoint: randomMove];
```

Question.

First - I want to initialize the moveValue = 0 so the array will start at first index. I just don't know where to put it and make it will not re-initialize moveValue back to 0 again when the view is changing back.

Second - Each time i switch view to generate random value and switch back to the first view. How can I make it accumulate to the previous value?

Please help. 
Thanks you.

ps. I'm very sorry if there is any bad grammar. It's not my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use NSUserDefaults to store the value and then read it, increment and save it again in each view.

You can then reset it on ApplicationLaunch if needed.

Example (Setting):

```
// Increment your number or whatever
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSNumber *randomMoveObj = [NSNumber numberWithInt:randomMove];
[prefs setValue:randomMoveObj forKey:@"randomMove"];
[prefs synchronize];
```

Example: (Getting):

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSNumber *randomMoveObj = [prefs valueForKey@"randomMove"];
NSInteger *randomMove = [randomMoveObj intValue];
// Do something with the number
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice I can do it now. I just don't know how to save the integer data, just saw only for string data. I'm very new to Xcode so i don't know which command to use.

Answer (score 0):

1. Initialize in ViewDidLoad.
2. Do you have it successfully switching between views?  In the code that triggers that action, you can increment the variable.

Comment: 1.Initialize in ViewDidLoad won't work when I change back to first view it become 0 again

2.Yes I can but in the first view won't keep the value that I increase.

Comment: So you are using non-retained views?

Comment: After I try randomly I can do it now. 
Thank you for your response. ^w^